# Unit test in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I have a UIbutton in my app. When I click the button, it removes the last object in a NSMutableArray. For this, I want to write unit tests.Please any one give me your suggestion.

I use this code for knowing when a click on the UIButton was performed:

```
[viewControllerObject.backButton1 sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Thanks,
Ricky.

Comment: wt u want ?? u want to create method of button for last obj from array

Comment: I am using unit testing so how to check that this button is click using like- XCTAssertTrue etc.

Answer (score 3):

At a "unit" level there are two things you're testing:

- does tapping the button send the action method?
- does the action method remove the last object from an array?

Ignore the first one, that's Apple's problem (or charitably it's an integration test). The second is straightforward if you think about the Assemble, Act, Assert process:

1. Assemble: build your view controller and its content array.
2. Act: call the action method.
3. Assert: check that the last object was removed.

```
-(void)testRemovalOfLastObjectOnButtonAction
{
    //... build and populate the view controller
    id lastObject = [array lastObject];
    [viewController buttonTapped: sender];
    STAssertFalse([array containsObject: lastObject], @"Object %@ should be removed", lastObject);       
}
```

Note I test explicitly whether the last object was removed, not whether the count was decremented: that could happen if *any* object were removed.

Comment: Hi OMZ,I get test failure,when i execute the above code.it correct or not?

Comment: @user1844142 what specifically is the failure? If it's that the assertion's failing, then your code isn't removing the object from the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several different ways. A suggestion would be to watch this great [tutorial](http://qualitycoding.org/uiviewcontroller-tdd/)

The video explains how to unit test in UIKit.

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

XCode has native support for Unit Tests. If you start a new project, look for the check mark that says 'Include Unit Test'. If you use that, you will have a folder called `<project_name>Tests`. Open the .m file in there, and you'll see a `- (void)testExample` method where you can put your tests.

You can use a number of functions to test, like `STAssertTrue` and `STAssertNotNil`. Check out the Apple docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/03-Writing_Test_Case_Methods/writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH4-SW1

In your case, you could probably do something like this:

```
NSInteger arrayCount = mArray.count;
[yourInstance performButtonAction];
STAssertEquals(arrayCount -1, mArray.count);
```

Comment: how to call buttonAction from apptest.m to viewcontroller.

Comment: As the tests run standalone, you could create your viewController in the `setup` method. That way you have a local reference to it.